# Magento HTTPS redirects to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to have all the web in HTTPS, so I put like in the screenshot. The problem is that when I click in a product or other link (organic) in Google redirects to the homepage.
[image]

```sh
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First you should have a SSL certificat in your domaine
2. In Unsecure group, you put http without **s**
3. You dont need a rewrite in .htaccess
4. Reindexall and clear your cache
5. you should have all the url, media, images, external url in https, otherwise google shows you an error

Comment: Hello, I have like this (with the htaccess I put) and nothing, when I enter in my website www.espamoto.com and I click in a product, category... go to HTTP instead HTTPS

Comment: because your domain `http://www.espamoto.com/` is not in https

Comment: Can you explain me? Or how to do it? Because I don´t know what I have to do now :)

Comment: This is a host part, you have to contact him

Comment: They have told me that it´s installed correctly in the server

Comment: I dont know, i see in my browser that it's not secure, maybe you have to wait a little bit the time the certificate takes effect! im not sure

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my htaccess. The problem is that all products with HTTP redirects to my homepage

```
*enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]*
```